# AWS Lambda reduce request image size

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am currently sending an image file to API Gateway, that then runs a lambda function for compression and storing in s3. Is there a way to limit the image size to make it maximum 1MB? I don't want to run my lambda function for huge images?

Comment: Before you compress and store the image, do you want your lambda to error or just not process any file more greater than 1MB?

Comment: Either would work to be honest @AlbertMarrero I would like to hear both options and their trade-offs